# ¿Qué significa en esta canción "los trillos de la entrega"?

Tags: definiciones

De la RAE, trillo significa

> 1. m. Instrumento para trillar, que comúnmente consiste en un tablón con pedazos de pedernal o cuchillas de acero encajadas en una de sus caras.
> 2. m. Can. y Am. Senda formada comúnmente por el tránsito.

¿Qué significa en la canción de Silvio Rodríguez *Requiem* la palabra "trillos"?

Contexto:

> "(...) Ojalá nunca sepas cuanto amaba,
>      descubrirte los trillos de la entrega,
>      ni el secreto esplendor con que esperaba,
>      tu reclamo de amor que ya no llega (...)"

Answer (score 1):

Lo importante es analizar el contexto en que se usa la palabra. Originalmente el trillo como instrumento lo que hace es dejar un rastro, sendero, camino, pero obviamente ese significado no es literal en el contexto de la canción.
La estrofa describe un encuentro físico (con tono sexual) entre la persona quien canta y su amante(que se entiende que se están separando).

> Ojalá nunca sepas cuanto amaba descubrirte los trillos de la entrega

los trillos de la entrega es el conjunto de caricias, el lenguaje, las formas, las miradas que conllevan a una entrega de amor(encuentro sexual). En otras palabras es el camino o rastro intangible compuesto por los elementos antes mencionados.

De una forma mas coloquial y explícita podría entenderse de esa frase:
*

> Ojalá nunca sepas cuánto amaba todos los detalles que precedían a que
>   tu me reclames(exijas) que te hiciera el amor.

*